# Pre-Flight Software

Tags: print-design, print-production

I recently started a job with a monthly publication. I wanted to know what the options for pre-flight software are. I know of Acrobat, but it has been questionable at times, in terms of pointing of resolutions. Any advice or recommendations would be great!

Comment: What specifically did you find questionable while using Acrobat?

Answer (score 3):

I would take a look at this site. http://www.vigc.org/standard-preflight-profiles/
These Profiles that are free to use are great for starting out understanding preflight and different methods that are used in the industry. I use one of them most of the time for Sheetfed CMYK.
I have used some of these profiles to get Clients started looking at preflight and how to use some of the Adobe Products. I would also contact a few printers that you might have in mind to use. If they recommend or help out they probably will be a good printer to use.

---

I am not affiliated with this Company so please understand I am only sharing what I have found to be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to GD.  Posting link only answers is frowned upon on the community because if the link were to go down your answer would be useless.  Please disclose what the link is about.

Answer (score 1):

We need to know a little more about your pre flight expectations and such before offering a concrete answer, but PitStop is always available:

http://www.enfocus.com/en/pitstop-pro-12/

Comment: Thanks. I just stumbled upon pitstop and it seems very helpful. I am mainly concerned with image resolution, CMYK color, spot color correction, ect.  I have also heard that there are some online programs in which advertisers would submit their artwork and the program would pre-flight them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, then PitSTop is going to be the solution for you. It is not cheap, but very customizable and automatable.

Answer (score 0):

Indesign can be used for preflight, but it depends on exactly what your specific concern is and how demanding your expectations...